# Why Does get_posts() Return an Empty Set?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, get-posts

I'm writing a custom plugin that is initialized at `init`. This plugin is trying to query for some custom post types already stored in the DB.

Here's my code:

```
$args = array()
$myposts = get_posts( $args );  
print_r($myposts);
```

No matter what arguments I pass into the $args array I don't get anything. For example:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'page' );
```

Now, to my confusion if I use the exact same arguments with `get_pages()` I get a result.

Maybe this has something to do with when WP Query is initialized?

Comment: Is this correct from your code? `$myposts = get_posts( );` i.e. you're *not passing `$args` to `get_posts()`*?

Comment: @ChipBennet, Good catch! That was just a typo on my part and wasn't causing the issue. I updated the code to fix the typo. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that is was a simple problem. [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) has various default settings, one of which is that the `post_status` is set to `public` and my custom post type which doesn't use `post_status` used the default value, `draft`.

To fix this you can either query by post status (see the code below) or change the data in the DB.

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_type'   => 'your_custom_post_type'
);
```

Comment: Wow, same problem, that was ridiculous.

Comment: In my case, the problem was that by default it shows only posts of type "post", so to get custom posts you should set args array key - value pair accordingly